# ifilter for search in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search

We ahave scenario hwere we configured our sharepoint 2010 search to a folder which is having xml files and when we try to find the results for example if we are searching for japan  we are getting as 180-12.xml but we need as in wording as japan to show in results.So is there any way to make the xml files internally crawled so that we can get the desired reults.can we use ifilter to crawl intenal elements of xml files to show up in results.How to use ifilter in that case please provide some useful links and information.Please help me out with suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if search is correctly crawling the XML content if it is returning appropriate values in the results.  In your case, you probably need to customize the search results web part to display the information you desire.

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for the response but is there any way to make our search to hit the internal property of xml file  to show up in results..what would be the best ways to do so..please suggest on this thanks

Answer (score 0):

you would need a 3rd party iFilter, there are plenty on google, but I have never seen on that is free sorry.

You could set out to write you're own but the only Microsoft article I can find is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916793.aspx)